# Returning something other than -1 index

Tags: python, list

Hi I would like to know how I can have my code below return the following given the input

```
split_sentence("doghellomeyayahell")
```

return

```
["dog","hellomeyayahell",""]
```

instead of

```
['dog', 'hellomeyayahel', 'l']
```

I know the problem is that since the thing cannot find the `'hello'` string it returns the `-1` index. If possible how would I make it so the above would work?

```
def split_sentence(s):
    lst = []
    first = s.find('hello')
    firsts = s[0:first]
    third = s.find('hello', first +2, len(s))
    thirds = s[third:len(s)]
    second = s[first:third]
    lst.append(firsts)
    lst.append(second)
    lst.append(thirds)
    return lst
```

Comment: Why should the second string be "hellomeyayahell"? If you really split on "hello", the second string should be "meyayahell".

Comment: second part is including hello which is why it looks from the first till the third

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it return something else, so you have to test the return value.

```
if third == -1:
    third = len(s)
thirds = s[third:]
```

You can also use `try/except` with `index`:

```
try:
    third = s.index('hello', first + 2)
except:
    third = len(s)
```